# An iPod, iPhone, and an iPad on 2 Apple IDs

Tags: ipod-touch, ipad, iphone, apple-id, switching

I have one iPod touch and my dad has a iPhone and a iPad. I use my dad's Apple ID. My dad has many apps and if I want a game/app that normally costs money he mostly has it, so I can install it for free. Now I want to make a new account but my dad says that I can't install his apps anymore so that I have to pay the apps again. E.g: My dad has cut the rope and I want it too, can I just switch accounts and install it or do I have to buy it myself on my own account? And when I make a new ID, do I lose my apps than?

Answer (score 3):

You can install and use apps bought via different Apple IDs on the same device. In case of application updates you have to be logged in with the matching ID to load the update though.